# How do I keep track of the score in a quiz?

Tags: javascript

I tried to put the code into a function in a class.

```
var score = 0;
for (var a = 0; a <= 5; a++) {
  if (userinput[i] == this.ans) {
    score += 1;
  } else {
    score += 0;
  }
}
console.log("Your score is " + score + "/5.");
```

The output will always show 5 even though the answers are wrong.

Comment: what is `i` in `userinput[i]`?

Comment: What are `userinput[i] and this.ans`?

Comment: add more information

Comment: please add more information on what is this.ans and userinput[i]

Comment: `userinput[i]` should probably be `userinput[a]`

Comment: this.ans is a parameter in a class and userinput is an input.question. For the userinput[i], I am not that sure about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll have the user *submit* a form and the form data is collected into an array, here is how I suggest calculating the score.

```
let answers = ['red', 'purple', '7', '12', 'train'];
let user = ['red', 'green', '7', '10', 'car']
let score = 0;

user.forEach(function(userResponse, index){
    if (userResponse === answers[index]){
        score++;
    }
})

// expect 2/5
console.log(`Your score is ${score}/5`);
```

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/GroovyJS/pbt50L3h/